# Should we have same or different route for external and local request

Tags: security, api

I'm building an externalized API for developers who want to develop their own app based on our API. Here is my question; the API provides the ability to let other developers make external requests to our server, but should we handle the same request in same route for local and external request for same function?

For example:

we have a login route in API `/api/v1/login` this route provides the ability to make login request to this API in other site but when our local site want to let user login should we use the same path `/api/v1/login` or we should make another route for local request `/auth`

Is there any security issue if using the same route for the external request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main security issue would be that there wouldn't actually be a difference between your external API and your "local" API. If both are using the same paths to do the same things, and are using the same backend functionality to do so, they aren't different. This isn't really a security problem so long as you are still properly controlling API access appropriately, i.e. through API keys, though your client would have to use those same access controls.

Comment: Then, will there be a priority level like serving local request first then external request? or it's line up from the request time?